# Invalid mime type & token character in "gml/2.1.2" posting XML * RestTemplate

Tags: xml, mime-types, resttemplate, geoserver, gml

i am trying to send an XML within the body of a postforEntity request so i can query with the xml through the url request, but getting this error

```
Invalid mime type "text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2": Invalid token character '/' in token "gml/2.1.2"
```

here is my resttemplate:
         List coords = new ArrayList();

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/postCoord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response postCoord(@RequestBody Coords coord) {
    coords.add(coord);
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String XML =<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:xsi=\"http://..... </wfs:GetFeature>
 ResponseEntity<String> coords = restTemplate.postForEntity(
  "http://localhost:9095/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=text/xml&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=topp:states&STYLES&LAYERS=topp:states&INFO_FORMAT=gml:2.1.2&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-129,24,-63,50&Content-Type=application/xml",XML,String.class);
    // Create Response Object
    Response response = new Response("Done", coords);
    return response;
```

this was the USA Population map in the geoserver and iam trying to find where the point in the xml file is located in the bbox given in the url request

Comment: What is throwing the error?

Comment: i fount that spring restTemplate is causing problem with the geoserver so i tried java resttemplate and it worked.